# Break вне цикла, исправьте ошибку. Заранее спасибо

Tags: pascal

```
var a,b,c,d,e:integer;
begin
for a := 1 to 50 do
writeln('a =', a);
begin
for b:= 1 to 50 do
writeln('b =', b);
for c:=1 to 50 do
writeln('c =', c);
for d:=1 to 50 do
writeln('d =', d);
for e:=1 to 100 do
writeln('e =', e);
if a + c + d = 50 then
if e - 30 + b = 50 then
writeln('some message', 50 + 50 + 30 + a + b + c + d + e);
break;
end;
end.
```